# Chrome Extension - Passing variables from HTML file to .js file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to pass a variable from the HTML of my Chrome extension into my content_script.js file. First time using javascript so I'm pretty lost. I have tried a few things but none of them seem to work. Here is my latest attempt:

popup.html

```
<html>
<head><title>activity</title></head>
<body>
<input id="email" type="email" placeHolder="Email" /> <br />
<button id="clickactivity">Create Account</button>  <br />
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function injectTheScript() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
    //and inject the script in it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"});
});
}

document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```

content_script.js

```
function registerAccount() {
    regEmail = document.getElementById("email");
    document.getElementById("register-email").value=regEmail.value;
}

registerAccount();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content script and your popup script run on different documents: you cannot access a variable of one of them from the other directly.

Try with this:

**popup.js**

```
document.getElementById('clickactivity').onclick = () => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: `
        var inputToFill = document.getElementById('register-email');
        if (inputToFill) inputToFill.value = '${document.getElementById('email').value}';
    `});
};
```

Other options may be using [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) or synchronisation through [storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Answer (score 0):

The document variable of the page is not the same as the one from the popup. You need to pass the input email value on the executeScript function.

Your need to get the input value using the document variable of your popup window, then inject that code on the page.

`popup.js`

```js
// make sure your popup was loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', function () {
  // if you pass tabId as null, it already gets the active tab from the current window
  // assuming that register-email exists on the page that in you'll insert this script code
    const emailFromPopup = document.getElementById('email').value
    const code = 'document.getElementById("register-email").value =' + `'${emailFromPopup}'`
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code });
  })
})
```

Comment: Should I add this to the end of popup.js or or put it inside the injectTheScript() function?

Comment: You don't need that function. This is the whole code that goes in `popup.js`.

Comment: You also won't need a `content_script.js`

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering. I did try that and got this error: "popup.js:8 (anonymous function)" and then it highlighted the last "}"

Comment: I thought it might be a missing parentheses but then i get an error on line 6: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null"

Comment: Yeah, there was a missing parenthesis. I've edited my response. Forgot to listen to the button click event.

Comment: The register-email must exists in the page after you click on the popup button.

Comment: Still getting that same error. Heres the URL: https://www.spotify.com/us/signup/

Is it just the popup.js that I had to change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188529/discussion-between-seb-tota-and-herodrigues).

Comment: Ok, now it's correct. Just tried on my computer. Sorry for the confusion. Yeah, you just need the popup.js.

Comment: Unfortunately i keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null". I've tried a few different things and nothing seems to work.